# Permission Denied in OpenCart?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, permission-denied

I have installed a extension in OpenCart 2.3.0.2. Installation is successful. But now I can't modify the extension according to my needs. When I click on the edit button. It's showing me "Permission denied" message (screen shot attached).[image]  I've searched a lot over the internet, but haven't found any concrete solution which matched with my issue. I can't understand where to look in to solve this issue actually.

I need to solve this issue. Hope you guys will help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible causes of this problem:

1. Did you actually run the install on the extension after you copied the files up to your site?  This would have been done in Admin->Extensions->Extensions, then select the extension type, then hit the "+" sign for the extension.
2. Check Admin->System->Users->Users to be sure your User Group is
       "Administrator."
3. Check the file under `admin/controller` for the extension, and look for a check of `hasPermission`.  It will look like this:

   if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/YOUR_EXTENSION')) {
     $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
   }

   This will show you where to look in the database.  Look at the table `oc_user_group`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing permissions in your User Group.

To solve this go to Admin panel -> System -> Users -> User Groups -> and edit User Group of your account (you can know what it is in System -> Users -> Users -> and edit your account)

On this page you can set permissions 'Access Permission' and 'Modify Permission'. Click 'Select All' for both and 'Save'.

After that you should be able to access your extension. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the following issues:

1) Permissions for the extension (You can change them in User Groups as Andre said)

2) The url of the extension (route= ... ) is wrong, or

3) Files of the extension are missing.